# Регулярное выражение для замены первой найденной буквы в слове

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот регулярное выражение которое заменяет все буквы "а" на "о" в строке:

```
import re

sentence = 'Saame kind of raandom sentence!'

result = re.sub(r'a', 'o', sentence)
print(result)
```

Но как заменить только первую встреченную букву в каждом слове, а не все буквы в целом предложений?
То бишь:

input: Same kind of random sentence!

output: Some kind of rondom sentence!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заменить найденное этим:

```
^([^a]*)a(.*)$
```

Вот этим:

```
\g<1>o\g<2>
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/QyYwVU/1

Сгенерированный код:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^([^a]*)a(.*)$"

test_str = "Same kind of random sentence!"

subst = "\\g<1>o\\g<2>"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Для первой буквы в каждом слове можно использовать *variable-width negative lookbehind*, который поддерживается в стороннем модуле `regex`:

```
import regex

re = r'(?<!\w*a\w*)a'

test_str = 'Same kind of random sentence!\naab bba xaxxaa xxx\naaaaaaaaa bbbaaaaaabbbbbb'

subst = r'o'

result = regex.sub(re, subst, test_str, 0, regex.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

sentence = 'Saame kind of a raandom aaaa sentence! vvavaa'

result = re.sub('a(\w*)', r'o\1', sentence)
print(result)
```

**Результат**

```
Soame kind of o roandom oaaa sentence! vvovaa
```